# How to enable hardware encryption on my Crucial MX500 drive

Tags: debian, ubuntu, hard-disk, ssd, disk-encryption

I have a Crucial MX500 1TB drive and it supports hardware encryption. I need to attach it to my Raspberry Pi 4 running ubuntu 20.04 and enable encryption. I also need the drive to be auto attached to the pi with the saved password during startup. It is not the boot drive it is just an another drive that is attached to the pi.
The product page for the SSD says it supports Microsoft® eDrive, IEEE-1667, and TCG Opal 2.0.

Thanks

Comment: automatically unlocking the encrypted disk makes the encryption rather meaningless as someone with access to the device can just extract the encryption key/password from where ever it's stored at the same time they pick up the encrypted disk itself.